# Deselect all other class elements when this element is changed (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few `<select>` elements that all have the same class `alternate-linked-select-box`. The intention here, is that when a change occurs to one select box, all the other ones should be deselected. Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".alternate-linked-select-box").on('change',(e) => {
        $(".alternate-linked-select-box").not($(e.target)).each((i,obj) => {
            $(obj).val([]);
        });
        // $(".alternate-linked-select-box").each((i,obj) => {
        //     if ($(obj) !== e.target) {
        //         console.log("We in here 2")
        //         $(obj).prop("selected", false);
        //     }
        // });
    });
});
```

Where the commented part demonstrates another approach I have tried to use. I have also tried to make use of `$(this)` but this also seems not to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `not($(e.currentTarget))` (to identify the element to which the event-handler is bound? Or, more easily, just use a regular function instead of an Arrow function which would allow you to use `this`/`$(this)`, allowing `not(this)` to work as I think you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the option and set selected to false

```js
// var sels = $(".alternate-linked-select-box").on("change", function() {
//   sels.not(this).find("option:selected").prop("selected", false);
// });

var sels = $(".alternate-linked-select-box").on("change", e => 
  sels.not(e.target).find("option:selected").prop("selected", false)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="alternate-linked-select-box">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<select class="alternate-linked-select-box">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<select class="alternate-linked-select-box">
  <option></option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```